# Image not showing on browser

Tags: html, css

does anyone know why the image added as

```
   &--2 {
      background-image: url(../assets/img/nat-6.jpg),
        linear-gradient(to right, $secondary-dark, $secondary-light);
    }
```

are not showed on the website, while same path into the `<img>` works instead.

Actually when I remove the dots on developer tools image is not showed, if I add them back (from dev tool on firefox) the image is showed correctly, but adding them back on VSCode doesn't make them show in dev tool... (hopefully I was clear :P)

Comment: Since you're using relative paths, is it possible your CSS and HTML files are in different directories? If so, I think the problem is that your CSS needs to go one directory higher to find the image -- `../../assets/img/nat-6.jpg`.

Comment: Relative URLs in external stylesheets are relative _to_ the URL of the stylesheet, not of the document that embeds the stylesheet.

Comment: Important: paths in your CSS file need to be relative to the location of your CSS file, not your HTML file, otherwise pages in different directories would not be able to share CSS without having to update the paths everywhere. However your structure, that's what you should keep in mind.

Comment: this is not usual CSS. It seems to be SASS (.scss) to me. If so, tag accordingly!

Comment: Open developer tools (F12 in Firefox and Chrome) and find the image request in "Network" tab. Is the call successful? "404 Not Found" means that the generated URL is not correct. Relative paths are hard to get right. If you aren't planning to move the site base URL frequently, use absolute paths and call it a day.

Comment: indeed they are 404...

Comment: Apparently it's a "loading" issue because I noticed from the dev tool the button I set width 45%, still shows as width:40%. The images above with directory path ../asset/img/image.jpg are now working properly...